# Unknown Database Connector Error

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I have a problem in server computer when I click button to show report(crystal)

This error have been shown:

> Unknown Database Connector Error Error in File List_Vagozari_Ensheab_Ab {6B911DD4-2B53-4005-9372-522C74B17AD0}.rpt: Unknown Database Connector Error

when i right click in database fields--->database expert... and click on Oledb(ADO) the following error has been appears : Unknown Database Connector Errore. and cant be create or see the connections...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal report files fill from DataTable Rows and you must adjust connection properties on Connection object.
   checking steps :
    1- Your application connect to server ( if not check server and client options such as firewalls and antivirus and DBMS server and Connetion string and ... )
    2- your commanad to server is fine (  syntax and result)
   please determine your Programming language

Comment: dear mojtaba,thanks for answere,but when i right click in database fields--->database expert... and click on Oledb(ADO) the following error has been appears : Unknown Database Connector Errore.  and cant be create or see the connections... thanks